# How do I include a link to a large file

Tags: support

I have a large text file (~6kB) that forms part of my challenge. How do I provide a link to download it instead of embedding the text in my question? I believe I have seen other questions do this but I don't have any examples.

Comment: Note that 6k does fit in a question (the limit is 30k characters). If you put the text in a code block it'll get a scrollbar anyway, so it won't take up all the much space. If that's still too much you can wrap it in a stack snippet and hide that snippet. Of course, having a raw file on pastebin like Calvin's Hobbies suggested is a bit more convenient for copying or downloading the data.

Answer (score 8):

## Host it elsewhere

And provide a link to where it is hosted.

Tons of sites let you do this for free. A very simple option is [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TjBdu144).

Google docs, Github, and Dropbox are some other common options that come to mind. Though for those you'll need an account.

If you specifically want a *download* link, these kind of sites usually have an option for that ([example](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=TjBdu144)). Though I'd advise against that here. I'd personally prefer to be directed to the raw text; I know how to download if I want to.

Comment: In the case of GitHub, I'd specifically recommend [gists](https://gist.github.com/). That and Pastebin are probably the best options. Dropbox is a bit dodgy since it gives you a download link, and Google Docs seems a bit overkill for plaintext files.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBüttner. I did what Calvin's Hobbies suggested.